# gcc -fstack-protector does not throw error

Tags: c, gcc, stack-overflow, stack-smash

Does someone know why the following lines of code throws a  *** stack smashing detected *** error

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  char x[16];
  strcpy(x,"aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa");
}
```

but the following code does not throw it?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    char x[16];
    x[17] = 'a';
}
```

Thank you!!

Comment: The behavior is undefined in both cases.

Comment: I dont understand that. What do you mean by undefined? @EOF

Comment: "Undefined" means that *anything* may happen. The compiler is not obligated to emit code that will crash, and it is not obligated to emit code that will actually execute the out-of-bounds accesses. *Anything* can happen, and the compiler is not required to be consistent about it. For example, my `gcc` with `-O3` completely optimizes away the out-of-bounds accesses and thus avoids even emitting stack-cookie code at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Overwriting `x[17]` doesn't overwite the [canary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_buffer_overflow#Stack_canaries)-value put before the return address by gcc.

Comment: And could you explain me why x[17] doesn't overwrite it? @Swordfish

Comment: You'd have to look at the assembly output ... how gcc manages the stack.